# How do I install SDL2 on mac using C preferably without X-Code?

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, sdl, sdl-2

I am using C and building a game I have tried every forum out there most seem to be in C++ and I would like to use SDL2 with C. I am using gcc compiler and the furthest I got was for it to compile with Gcc but no window would appear. Not code because grabbed it from a tutorial. I have tried with brew and the framework.

Could Somebody please walk me through the install process to get it working either with gcc or xcode

EDIT: On Catalina 10.15.6

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,
I figured it Out, those who are also having trouble you can here is my solution,

You download and install the framework into `Library/Frameworks` then once you are done that you will be able to compile using gcc with this command

```
gcc main.c -o run -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2_image
```

How ever as I mentioned before you can get the code to compile without a window appearing so here is the solution full credit to the forums and the User Sjr

https://discourse.libsdl.org/t/sdl2-compiles-but-doent-open-a-window-when-run/26867

and here is a link to how I got the compiler to work

https://youtu.be/BCcvwoIOHVI

The compile command is different so look in the comments the reply by ikokujin to the comment by Phraggers with a couple edits by me to include `gcc -o run`

Hope this info help's everyone who was stuck on this in their sdl2 project on Mac.

Thanks,
Winter_Ice